# Ionic 2 - Importing @ionic-native/geolocation causes build to fail

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, geolocation

What I have done:
I'm using Visual Studio, so I edited the package.json file by adding:
 - cordova-plugin-geolocation (inside cordovaPlugins array) 
 - @ionic-native/geolocation (inside dependencies object)

Then I go editing the app.module.ts file by adding:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
```

At this point, when I try to run the browser emulation I'll get the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) : main.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) : main.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) : polyfills.js
```

Also, I tried to import a fake package by writing:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/dfsdfdsf';
```

and I get no errors (even if, of course, it does nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put

```
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3"
```

in my package.json's dependencies.

I already had it under 'cordovaPlugins', but it seems it was not enough.
Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try running upgrading

```
npm i --save @ionic-native/geolocation@5.0.0-beta.14
```